# Horizontal buffering in extjs grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using buffered rendering mode in extjs 4.2 grid. This feature is really good as it handles large number of rows easily. But if the number of columns is 1500 and number of rows is 10 the grid becomes unresponsive and the browser is showing a message as  "not responsive due to a long running script". Has anyone tried using horizontal buffering similar to vertical buffering in extjs grid? Is there any grid component that supports horizontal buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Currently no plans to support it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it really difficult to implement it? Any idea that I could try to simulate horizontal scrolling? Any extjs grid plugins available/in development to support this?

Comment: Yes, it's somewhat complicated to implement. You'd need to roughly follow the same pattern as vertical scrolling, the logic would be the same at a high level. As I said in my answer, there are no plans to support it at the moment.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli any changes on supporting this? This would be nice addon for extremely large grids, especially on old PC'a and browsers. I think that not only I will be happy to test and give as much feedback as possible on this feature.